# What broswers don't support Cache Busting?

Tags: javascript, css, caching, browser-support

I've been working on an eCommerce site that recently did a big code release. We have been modifying/optimizing some of the .js and .css for a few months. Every time a user comes to the site they have to clear their cache.

We have started adding a query string to the urls
/Resources/Javascript/GuidedNavigation.js?v=1

However, from what I'm hearing not all browsers support this. I haven't been able to find an explanation as to what browsers support query strings. Presumably all modern browsers but we still have a decent amount of traffic coming in through IE7-IE9.

**What browsers support cache busting and query strings?**

Comment: I'm actually working on IE5 and I can tell you that it does not support this. It actually doesn't support a lot of thing so it's not an exemple....

Comment: It would be good if something like http://caniuse.com/ enlightened us on this capability :(

Comment: [Use HTTP `Cache-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching_FAQ) instead, it's an ancient thing (1999) and it might work on old IE's.

Comment: You could include the variable in the filename itself, that would ensure a new download, i.e. Do this `style_4rT5mL7.css` vs. `style.css?v=4rT5mL7`.

Comment: Browsers do not support ***query strings***?! Those have been in HTTP 1.0 since roughly 840 BC. I don't think there's any browser which does not support query strings. Perhaps some browser exhibits *incorrect caching behaviour for URLs with query strings*? That's a different story, but I'd be highly surprised by that as well. Again, 840 BC...

Comment: To clarify the question, what browsers support cache busting via query stings?

Comment: and I would love to see this site that is supporting ie5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> To clarify the question, what browsers support cache busting via query stings?

Cache busting isn't something browsers "support"; it's a technique that uses the standard behavior of browser caching.

Data is cached in the browser *per URL*. Each unique URL is supposed to represent a unique piece of data, which can be individually cached. **By appending a meaningless value in the query string, you change the URL, making it unique, causing the browser to download it because it doesn't have it cached yet.** That's all there is to it.

For this *not* to work a browser would have to have non-standard cache behavior and somehow consider two different URLs equal, and use a cached version of a different URL for a URL it has in fact not yet downloaded. I know of no browser which does this (doesn't mean it doesn't exist, but this would be *severely* broken).

Comment: Thanks for your help @deceze